# service locater pattern vs service aggregate factory on inheritance

Tags: asp.net-core, dependency-injection

Say I have a base class that needs a bunch of services. And this base class has some derived classes.

```
class BaseClass
{
    BaseClass(IServiceA srvA, IServiceB srvB) { ... }
}
```

To inherit from this base class with DI, I need to repeat the constructor parameters in the derived class:

```
class DerivedClassA
{
    DerivedClassA(IServiceA srvA, IServiceB srvB) : base(srvA, srvB) {}
}
```

When later the base class needs a new dependency, I will have to change the base class as well as the derived class. Imagine the nightmare when there are a few derived classes.

I did some research and there seems to be a solution to this which is service aggregate factory (or a similar term):

```
interface IServiceFactory
{
    IServiceA getSrvA();
    IServiceB getSrvB();
}

class ServiceFactory : IServiceFactory
{
     public ServiceFactory(IServiceA srvA, IServiceB srvB) { ... }

     public IServiceA IServiceFactory.getSrvA() => this._srvA;

     public IServiceB IServiceFactory.getSrvB() => this._srvB;
}

class BaseClass
{
    BaseClass(IServiceFactory factory)
    {
        this._srvA = factory.getSrvA();
        this._srvB = factory.getSrvB();
    }
}

class DerivedClassA : BaseClass
{
    DerivedClassA(IServiceFactory factory) : base(factory) { ... }
}
```

This way, I only need to change the `ServiceFactory` every time when I need to add more services to the classes without changing them.

But then there is the `IServiceProvider` which is the default DI container in .net core. So I can do:

```
class BaseClass
{
    public BaseClass(IServiceProvider provider)
    {
        this._srvA = provider.GetRequiredService<IServiceA>();
        this._srvB = provider.GetRequiredService<IServiceB>();
    }
}

class DerivedClassA : BaseClass
{
    public DerivedClassA(IServiceProvider provider) : base(provider) {}
}
```

It looks the same as the service aggregate factory but people say it is an anti pattern to directly use the `IServiceProvider`. So I am confused. Which option should I pick?

Comment: Don't inherit from a base class - prefer composition over inheritance and inject the functionality provided by the base class

Answer (score 2):

> Say I have a base class that needs a bunch of services. And this base class has some derived classes.

Stopped reading here and you should have too. This is a clear indicator that your base class does way toooooooo much. This violates the SRP (Single Responsibility Principle) from [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID).

Constructor injections makes design flaws (such as SOLID violations) very obvious and you should pay attention to it, since it tells you when your class is having too much responsibilities (a class trying to do too much).

First and foremost, you need to think why your base class needs these dependencies and change this.
Your question is way to abstract, so can't tell you why your class may need that many dependencies.

If your class **really** needs all these dependencies, consider using an facade. A facade is another class, which hides the complexity and dependencies behind an easy to use interface thus reducing the number of dependencies. See Mark Seemann's [Refactoring to Aggregate Services](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/).

A facade is more than just a class which offers an easy access to other dependencies (i.e. a class having only 5 properties which represent other services). A facade will hide the dependencies if possible and offer methods to easily access the functionality behind it,i.e. `.GetDrives` method could enumerate the hardware devices and scan it for partitions and listen every properly formatted partition so that doesn't need to be repeated by the calling code.

Imagine you have services like `IMemoryService`, `ICpuService`, `IDiskService`, `INetworkService` and inject these in all your base classes. That's a lot of dependencies.

Instead you could have a `IComputerServices` interface which gives you access to all these services hidden by easy to use APIs/methods/properties (i.e. a `IComputerServices.CopyFileTo` method which abstracts all the copy operations in a single easy to use method and inject these in your services. Now you can copy a file like `computerServices.CopyFileTo(sourceFile, destinationFile)`.

If a new dependency comes in, such as `IDisplayService`, you just add it the the facade service and it will be available in all your classes which also inject `IComputerServices`.

Comment: This helps a lot. The reason for these dependencies in the base class is that my base class doesn't do anything but holds some common behaviours/properties for all these sub classes and it is these sub classes that require their own services respectively. But as @qujck said, I might need to do composition rather than inheritance.